# Bad Request 400 when requesting Google OAuth2 token, Java

Tags: java, http, oauth-2.0, google-api

I've gotten an auth code from doing a "GET" request and signing in, and I'm trying to use that code to get an auth token using an http "POST", but I always get response code 400. My code is as follows:

```
// Create HTTP Objects
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");

// Add Header
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// Create Parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", client_id));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", client_secret));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", redirect_uri));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));

// Add Parameters and Excecute
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

It seems to match perfectly the documentation they provide here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out, it was as simple as it took long enough to debug my code for the auth code from Google to expire.

I got a new code from Google and it worked.